# How to perform query in SQL in an Athena database that returns data count grouped by month?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I am struggling with this query to receive my data grouped by month instead of every day. Right now it gives me results for every day for each product code which makes my Excel file too large to send via email.

```
SELECT line_item_usage_account_id,  
line_item_product_code, 
         SUM(line_item_unblended_cost) AS cost, 
         SUM(CASE   
    WHEN line_item_product_code = 'AmazonEC2' THEN  
    line_item_unblended_cost * 0.89 
    ELSE line_item_unblended_cost * 0.85 END) AS discounted_cost,   
     CAST(line_item_usage_start_date AS DATE) AS start_day, CAST(line_item_usage_end_date AS DATE) AS end_day   
FROM cost_management_2ef5a060_prod  
WHERE line_item_usage_account_id IN ('123456789122')    
        AND line_item_usage_start_date  
    BETWEEN DATE '2019-06-01'   
        AND DATE '2020-01-01'   
GROUP BY  line_item_usage_account_id, CAST(line_item_usage_start_date AS DATE), CAST(line_item_usage_end_date AS DATE),line_item_product_code   
HAVING sum(line_item_blended_cost) > 0  
ORDER BY  line_item_usage_account_id
```

Data Results:

[Current Data Results by Day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCqT2.png)

Data Results by Month

[Can my data look somewhat like this or in a way where I don't have so many rows?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pcJa.png)

Thank you!

Comment: In your `GROUP BY` clause you're grouping by `line_item_usage_start_date`. You can extract year-month with `year()`, `month()` functions, but using `date_trunc('month', line_item_usage_start_date)` might be more convenient. See more in Presto docs https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html.
(It this sufficient for you, let me know, I can convert this to an answer.)

Comment: I tried to modify the query using date_trunc: `SELECT line_item_usage_account_id,
      sum(line_item_unblended_cost) AS cost,
      DATE_TRUNC('month', line_item_usage_start_date) AS start_month, DATE_TRUNC('month', line_item_usage_end_date) AS end_month
FROM cost_management_2ef5a060_prod
WHERE line_item_usage_account_id IN ('123456789122')
GROUP BY  line_item_usage_account_id, line_item_usage_start_date, line_item_usage_end_date
HAVING sum(line_item_blended_cost) > 0
ORDER BY  line_item_usage_account_id;` but then I get even more rows than when I used the CAST function.

Comment: I get 961 rows when I used the date-trunc function, but only 64 rows when I used CAST function.

Answer (score 0):

The below query should help you, before you proceed the query is written on your current query output and start_day and end_day are actual date for which record is present. Also start_day is taken for considering the month, if end_day for that record lies in next month , then we can not calculate at all.

```
    select line_item_usage_account_id, date_format(date_parse(start_day ,'%c/%e/%Y' ), '%Y/%c') as Mo_Year,
    sum(discounted_cost) as discounted_cost 
    ,min(date_parse(start_day ,'%c/%e/%Y' )) as start_day,
    Max(date_parse(end_day ,'%c/%e/%Y' )) as end_day
    from <table_name>  
    group by date_format(date_parse(start_day ,'%c/%e/%Y' ), '%Y/%c'), line_item_usage_account_id
```

Comment: May I ask if I need what I need to replace '%c/%e/%Y' with? I'm sorry I am still new to SQL and don't know many things.

Comment: You can refer this page this is just to parse and format you have any data 
          https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html